# jquery: focus/blur events don't work after input replacement

Tags: jquery, dom, replace

I have a simple input element with the following attributes:

```
<input id="InputPassword" type="password" value="Password" class="initClass"/>
```

In order set a cross-browser placeholder for it I use testFocusBlur function

```
function testFocusBlur(){
$('input').focus(function () {
    if($(this).attr('type')=='text'){
       var campoPassword=$(this);
       replaceInputType(campoPassword[0], 'password')
    }
}).blur(function () {
    if($(this).attr('type')=='password'){
    var campoPassword=$(this);
    replaceInputType(campoPassword[0], 'text')
    }
});
$('input').blur();
```

}

which, on $(document).ready event:

1. calls the blur event on the input element;
2. if type=password call the replaceInputType javascript function;
3. replaceInputType function creates a new dom input element, set type=text for it, get the attributes of the old input elements and change the class from initClass to newClass;
4. append the new input element to the same div

the above works correctly but, once the new input element is set, and I focus on it, the initial testFocusBlur function doesn't work anymore

see: http://jsfiddle.net/4tRzs/2/

note: i don't want to set an inline function in the input such as onfocus="...."

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: There are many polyfills that you can use  https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `on` function from jQuery

```
$(document).on("focus" , "input", function(){
   ...
}
```

`on` is the old `live` function. [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You will have something like this in your function:

```
function testFocusBlur(){
$(document).on("focus", 'input', function () {
    if($(this).attr('type')=='text'){
       var campoPassword=$(this);
       replaceInputType(campoPassword[0], 'password')
    }
})
$(document).on("blur", "input", function () {
    if($(this).attr('type')=='password'){
    var campoPassword=$(this);
    replaceInputType(campoPassword[0], 'text')
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, it certainly works but... in case I don't want to use the "on" binding-method is there a way to provide, inside the function which recreate the input (ReplaceInputType), a new binding of the blur/focus events to the newly created input?

Comment: something like so:
function replaceInputType(oldObject, inputType) {
[.....]
[.....]
[.....]
oldObject.parentNode.replaceChild( newObject, oldObject );


"let this newly created object recognise the fucus/blur events to which was bind before"



return newObject;
}

Comment: You can call the testFocusBlur() function again when creating the new input. Other method I don't think there is.